# WMI call from WCF failed

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, wmi

I have a WCF method that connect to the WMI to query some AD info.

If I debug WCF locally, it works, i.e. ManagementObjectSearcher.Get() returns non-empty collection.

Once I publish WCF to IIS webserver, then have a client (a winform) calls the same method, it returns empty collection (no exception).

Any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is IIS Service hosted locally or some different machine ?

Comment: The WCF is running under its own application pool and this app pool uses a local user that is a member of administrators group.

Comment: have you checked the endpoint